# Error when compiling a Java file with an "Aux" class in it

Tags: java

I have a Java file containing a single public class (called `Test`) and a private class (called `Aux`).

When I call `javac Test.java`, I get the following error:

> Test.java:5: error: error while writing Aux:
>   C:\Users\Wolf\Desktop\java\Aux.class

I thought it might be a permissions issues, but I have Admin access to the folder (the Java JDK is on my path).

Also, if I comment out the `Aux` class (leaving the `Test` class in), it works.

Any idea why it doesn't work with multiple classes in the same file?

Here's the code for `Test.java`:

```
class Aux {
}

public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code for `Test.java`...

Comment: If you have a file `Test.java`, the only public class you can have there is `class Test` - If you have classes with different access modifiers, and the public one is not Test, this will not work.

Comment: Unrelated, but why on earth would you be doing this in your desktop directory? Tangentially related to that-use source control. Get in the habit.

Comment: Thanks @dmitryro, so I can't include private helper classes in the same file as a public class? In that case, when do you use private classes?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a package level access, declare a package for that file with two classes and provide your source structure is consistent.

Comment: That code works for me using the Oracle jdk. Which jdk are you using?

Comment: @PaulHicks I'm using the Oracle JDK, version 10.0.1 with Windows 10.

Comment: Ah. I'm using 1.8.0_31. Try it there? Or at least with `-source 1.8 -target 1.8`?

Comment: @PaulHicks running with the "-source" and "-target" doesn't work, unfortunately. It does seem like this should work (and the documentation suggests that it should). There's just something frustratingly weird about my environment.

Comment: The question title should be updated to mention "aux": this needs to be findable when, in 3 years time, it happens to some other unfortunate developer...

Comment: Good point. I'll make the change. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a duplicate that lists more illegal file names. Note that this only is a hard-to-find problem when you put the class with the illegal name in the same source file as another public class. If you had put `class Aux` inside its own `Aux.java` class, you would have found out that it was an illegal file name, the moment that you tried to save `Aux.java`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in Windows, you cannot create a file named `Aux` for legacy reasons. It ought to work if you rename your class to something other than `Aux`.

Comment: Ooo. Nice catch.

Comment: Wow, that's crazy! I never would have known. Thanks!